# GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "import"

Tags: webpack, graphql

I wanted to use a .grapgql file to have my queries there, but I get

ERROR in ./src/myfilepath/queries.graphql
Module build failed (from (webpack)-graphql-loader/lib/loader.js):
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected Name "import"

If I change it back to a .js file it works fine.

I tried the steps here https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-graphql-loader

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-graphql-loader 

npm install --save-dev graphql
```

And

Add webpack-graphql-loader to your webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [ // or "loaders" for webpack 1.x
      { test: /\.graphql?$/, loader: 'webpack-graphql-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

But it is still happening.

This is the content of one of the files

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const CONTACT_MUTATION = gql`
 mutation CreateSubmissionMutation($clientMutationId: String!, $firstName: String!, $lastName: String!, $email: String!, $message: String!){
    createSubmission(input: {clientMutationId: $clientMutationId, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, email: $email, message: $message}) {
      success
      data
    }
  }
`
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have JavaScript syntax inside a file that's supposed to be just GraphQL. Change the contents of the file to just your query:

```
mutation CreateSubmissionMutation($clientMutationId: String!, $firstName: String!, $lastName: String!, $email: String!, $message: String!){
  createSubmission(input: {clientMutationId: $clientMutationId, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, email: $email, message: $message}) {
    success
    data
  }
}
```

The loader will parse the contents of the file and return a DocumentNode in the same way that `graphql-tag` parses a string.

Comment: and then how would I import the mutation in the js file? And also how would I reference them, if I have many? Do I import the complete file?

Comment: It doesn't look like that loader supports multiple operations per file. You should probably use the loader that comes with `graphql-tag`, which will export each operation as a named export.